# How to compile php with specific versions of curl and openssl?

Tags: php, curl, openssl, php-7

I want to use the library that have specific requirements for php extensions. So I need to use `php 7.0` or `php 7.1` with such versions of php extensions:

- lib-curl >= 7.46.0 (with http/2 support enabled)
- lib-openssl >= 1.0.2e

How can I compile php with such requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two options.

You can install `lib-curl` 7.46.0 or greater on the machine, and then compile PHP with the `--with-curl` option. It will use the version of `lib-curl` on the machine. The same with `lib-openssl` and use `--with-openssl` when compiling.

Or ...

The [PHP documentation for openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php) shows you can provide a directory for openssl ... so if you want to compile with a specific version of `lib-openssl` you can pass in the directory to a specific version:

> To use PHP's OpenSSL support you must also compile PHP --with-openssl[=DIR] .

The same goes for `lib-curl` ([Here's the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php)):

> To use PHP's cURL support you must also compile PHP --with-curl[=DIR] where DIR is the location of the directory containing the lib and include directories.